# how can I delete a database from my phpmyadmin dashboard which named with multiple strings like "coming soon"?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

how can I delete a database from my phpmyadmin dashboard which named with multiple strings like "coming soon"?
I tried `drop database coming soon` but it's showing me this error.

```
drop database coming soon;
```

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'soon' at line 1

Comment: Use ticks ..  `drop database \`coming soon\``

Comment: use backticks mysql uses them as delimiter for table names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backticks are used in MySQL to select columns and tables from your MySQL source. In the example below we are calling to the table titled Album and the column Title. Using backticks we are signifying that those are the column and table names.  [RESOURCE](https://chartio.com/learn/sql-tips/single-double-quote-and-backticks-in-mysql-queries/#backticks)

```
SELECT `Album`.`Title`
FROM `Album` AS `Album`
GROUP BY `Album`.`Title`
ORDER BY `Title` ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

The thing that the article does NOT mention is the multiple stringed table or database names.  The above statement would work with, or without, backticks.  However this statement would not work without backticks:

```
SELECT `Album`.`Title One`, `Album`.`Title Two`
```